# Container fluid if screen width below width value

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstrap and after a while of googling and not finding appropriate answer I hope someone will be able to help me. What I' m trying to achieve is to have container fluid if width of screen is less than 1200px.

So for example, if screen width is 300, 600, 900, 1100 or whatever below 1200px, container should be fluid and if the screen width is more or equal to 1200px, container should be 1170px + gutter.

Is is possible to achieve this with bootstrap or do I need to override some `CSS` settings?

Comment: So, fixed width if `>= 1200px`, full width if `<= 1200px`?

Comment: fixed width if >= 1200px, full width if < 1200px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some time of browsing and trying and coding, the best solution for me was just to add

```
.container-fluid
{
max-width:1170px
}
```

Hope it helps to someone.